# Creating custom shipping method with options

Tags: magento

I need to create a custom shipping method for a company, which is some sort of agent for a bunch of actual carriers. So during the checkout process a customer should be able to see a list of carriers and prices depending on his location (delivery endpoint). The agent company provides the API for retrieving this kind of information, so I have to determine the best way for integrating the API into the checkout process and displaying the delivery options. I know I need to override some models, blocks and templates, but I don't know, where to start. Could you give me the right direction? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to override models. You just need to create a custom shipping method.
[This should help you](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/shipping/create-shipping-method-module).
Most of the magic happens in `collectRates()` method.
You can connect there to the different APIs you have for each shipping method just create a new object `$method = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');` set its title and price and append it to the result.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I've already read that article, but it seems like it's not exactly what I'm looking for. Let me just describe the steps: during checkout customer selects my custom shipping method and then he should be able to see the available carriers and corresponding prices (retrieved through agent company API) say in the form of dropdown list.